# JSF Facelets rendering problem

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem with my facelets:

I constricted a nav part that displays login information for about curren user and a logout button. Login works properly. But after a user logs out, the **nav part** of my page displays

```
Welcome, User (role)    [Logout_Button]
```

Whereas, what I want is the same thing that happens when you get to the login the first time:

```
Welcome, Guest
```

(Thank you Java drinker for those easy words :-))

**Here you can see part of my template:**

```
  <div id="metaContainer">
        <ui:include src="/metaMenu.xhtml" />
  </div>
```

**That's my nav part with login info** (called metaMenu.xhtml):

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <div id="login_info">
        <h:outputLabel value="Willkommen, "/>
        <h:outputLabel class="principal" value="#{metaNavData.principal}"/>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{metaNavData.role}"/>
    </div>
    <div id="meta_nav">
        <h:form name="loginform" rendered="#{authorisation.authenticated}">
        <h:commandLink action="#{loginController.logout}" rendered="#{authorisation.authenticated}">
        Logout</h:commandLink>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

As BalusC and Java Drinker assumed it could be a java logic problem. I first need to say, that I use **Apache Shiro** for security issues. So here is the relevant Java code:

**my loginController that contains the logout method:**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped //Mistake!!! That should be RequestScoped, see below
public class LoginController {

private Subject currentUser;  // import org.apache.shiro.subject.*;

public LoginController() {
    currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
}

public String logout() {
    if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
    currentUser.logout();
    }
    return "welcome.xhtml";
}
```

**And her you can see my backed bean 'authorisation'**, which is supposed to provide information that can be used to hide comonents like the loginbutton:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Authorisation {

    private Subject currentUser;

    public Authorisation(){
        currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    }

    public boolean getAuthenticated(){
        return currentUser.isAuthenticated();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying the <h:outputLabel value="Willkommen, "/>... part does not render once the user is logged out?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't get the problem. I think there's ambiguity in the word "render" which you're using. You aren't conditionally rendering anywhere in the login_info div of the code example, but you're telling so in the problem description. I think you *actually* meant "displayed value" or "returned value" where you said "rendered". This is in turn not a rendering problem, but a model / code-logic problem.

Comment: sorry for confusing words. my technical terms are sometimes not the right ones. but I will improve ! Thx for reading and for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so from what I understand, your problem is that even after a user logs out, the nav part of your page displays

```
Welcome, User (role)    [Logout_Button]
```

Whereas, what you want is the same thing that happens when you get to the login the first time:

```
Welcome, Guest
```

The problem, I think, is in your log out functionality. For whatever reason, even after you logout, `#{authorisation.authenticated}` is returning `true.` Secondly, `#{loginController.principal}` still contains the value of the previously logged in user, and his/her role. Are any of these beans session scoped perhaps, or caching the value somewhere?

And BalusC is right *(as usual)* in that you are using the word `rendered` here incorrectly. The button is the only element that is conditionally `rendered.` From what I see, the `Welcome, User(role)`, vs `Welcome, Guest` is based solely on the value in the `loginController.`

If you can post some of your java code for those beans and login/logout functionality, we can try to help further

Comment: Thank you for understanding -.- I gonna edit the whole post and add some java logic :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thank's to BalusC and Java Drinker for your help, I have found my stupid mistake:

> Are any of these beans session scoped
>   perhaps

That was the wrong part! I used SessionScoped for my controller instead of RequestScoped. So here is the right controller:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped  // Here was my mistake
public class LoginController {

private Subject currentUser;  // import org.apache.shiro.subject.*;

public LoginController() {
    currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
}

public String logout() {
    if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
    currentUser.logout();
    }
    return "welcome.xhtml";
}
```

I have found a very nice link about distinctions of managedBeans and how they should be scoped :-) [KLICk](http://java.dzone.com/articles/making-distinctions-between)

Perhaps this thread can give some inspiration for java beginner as I am too ;-)

Comment: That's great! Glad we could help.